# what does -append field work in QEMU

Tags: emulation, qemu

I saw this command to make image

```
qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb \
-no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1" \
-hda 2013-05-25-wheezy-raspbian.img
```

Here the `-append` field gives me some doubt...

It says `/dev/sda2`: does it refer to my own disk (`/dev/sda2`) ?

On manual page it says:

> `-append cmdline`
>
> Use cmdline as kernel command line

I'm confused here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The append line adds extra options to the kernel command line in UNIX derivatives. You can add many extra options such as

- root device (/dev/sda2 in your example)
- initrd file
- debugging options such as 'quiet'
- hdd emaulation (ide-scsi)
- boot type (single, rescue etc.)
- VGA mode

You can find which options you can pass to append line in QEMU kernel options manual : [page is now archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20131210001407/http://xecdesign.com/working-with-qemu/)

Edit:

If you want to pass different root partition you can pass via root=/dev/sdXX. You should display your disk layout with fdisk command if you don't know your image's root partition. Example of a sd card image disk layout:

```
root@pi# fdisk -l moebius.1.0.1.img 

Disk moebius.1.0.1.img: 943 MB, 943718400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 114 cylinders, total 1843200 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000714e9

            Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
moebius.1.0.1.img1            8192      122879       57344    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
moebius.1.0.1.img2          122880     1761279      819200   83  Linux
```

As you can see linux root partition is **2nd** partition, that means it will named /dev/**sda2** when you try to boot via qemu-system-arm.

Comment: thnks.....i thought /dev/sda2 will mess up with my disk /dev/sda2 but, i just did it....and it worked for me.....

Comment: if you can help me....who actually made: /dev/sda2
i just used the image and tutorial...was partition made in the image have i used to build it ....???